# html link to facebook won't work

Tags: html

My code:

```
<html>
<head>
<body>
<font size = "7" face = "Consolas"> Facebook: </font><br>
<a href = "https://www.facebook.com/******"><img src = "fbicon.png" width = "200" height = "200"> </a>
</body>
</head>
</html>
```

Our current lesson is on frames.
I have left and right frames. Where in the left frame, there's a menu, and one of which is "social networking sites". When I click on that, a list(pictures) of my sns will appear on the right frame. One is Facebook.
I'm trying to figure out how to link my Facebook page and make it appear on my right frame also.

Comment: On a side note. `font` tag is deprecated. Use `span` instead.

Comment: What exactly is going wrong? Code looks like it will work fine. Although there are many "best practice" points you haven't followed, none would stop this link from working.

Answer (score 0):

From this code you get Correct Facebook page . apart from that if you are facing issue please post CSS code as well

```html
<html>
<head>
<body>
<font size = "7" face = "Consolas"> Facebook: </font><br>
<a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_self">
 <img src="fbicon.png" width = "200" height = "200" />
</a>
</body>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you.
Uh, another question, i want to use target = "_self" instead of "_blank", and not I'm trying it but it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: No Check my updated code it works fine . when you click on image on same page Facebook will open . hope this will help .

Comment: Thanks again. (I guess it's my browser)